# Python - Search for a specific "var" using bs4

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

So I have been trying to learn a bit using scrape where I managed to scrape a site where it returns a massive of different var values such as:

```
var FancyboxI18nClose = 'Close';
var FancyboxI18nNext = 'Next';
var FancyboxI18nPrev = 'Previous';
var PS_CATALOG_MODE = false;
var added_to_wishlist = '.';
var ajax_allowed = true;
var ajaxsearch = true;
var attribute_anchor_separator = '-';
var attributesCombinations = [{"id_attribute":"100","id_attribute_group":"1","attribute":"38_5"},{"id_attribute":"101","id_attribute_group":"1","attribute":"39"},{"id_attribute":"103","id_attribute_group":"1","attribute":"40"},{"id_attribute":"104","id_attribute_group":"1","attribute":"40_5"},{"id_attribute":"105","id_attribute_group":"1","attribute":"41"},{"id_attribute":"107","id_attribute_group":"1","attribute":"42"},{"id_attribute":"108","id_attribute_group":"1","attribute":"42_5"},{"id_attribute":"109","id_attribute_group":"1","attribute":"43"},{"id_attribute":"111","id_attribute_group":"1","attribute":"44"},{"id_attribute":"112","id_attribute_group":"1","attribute":"44_5"},{"id_attribute":"132","id_attribute_group":"1","attribute":"45"},{"id_attribute":"113","id_attribute_group":"1","attribute":"46"}];
```

There is alot more of course and they all contain just in var. However what I want to do is to only be able to scrape one of the values - *var attributesCombinations* meaning that I basically just want to print out that value where I afterwards can use json.loads where I can scrape the json easier aswell.

What I tried to do is following:

```
try:
    product_li_tags = bs4.find_all(text=re.compile('attributesCombinations'))
except Exception:
    product_li_tags = []
```

but that gave ma e result of all of the "var" start to where `attributesCombinations`.

```
['var CUSTOMIZE_TEXTFIELD = 1;\nvar FancyboxI18nClose = \'Close\';\nvar FancyboxI18nNext = \'Next\';\nvar FancyboxI18nPrev = \'Previous\';\nvar PS_CATALOG_MODE = false;\nvar added_to_wishlist = \'The product was successfully added to your wishlist.\';\nvar ajax_allowed = true;\nvar ajaxsearch = true;\nvar allowBuyWhenOutOfStock = false;\nvar attribute_anchor_separator = \'-\';\nvar attributesCombinations = [{"id_attribute":"100","id_attribute_group":"1","att...........
```

How do I make it so it only prints out *var attributesCombinations* ?

Comment: Do you want a regular expression to just match `var attributesCombinations = [ ... ];` ? Try `re.compile(r'var attributesCombinations = (\[.*?\])');` and then access `match.groups(1)`

Comment: Correct, I only want the expression that matches! I quite haven't used regex alot. would you mind to try to create a answer for it that maybe solves it for the future people aswell :) ? @Corion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A regular expression that extracts (just) the parts from `attributesCombinations` to the end of the statement is

```
var attributesCombinations = (\[.*?\])
```

In Python, you can create the regular expression easily as

```
re.compile(r'var attributesCombinations = (\[.*?\])');
```

Comment: Im not sure but isn't it supposed to search through all bs4 before it can do a re.compile or soemthing like that? because how else it would know what to complie?

Comment: I tried to do `for tag in bs4.find_all(re.compile(r'var attributesCombinations = (\[.*?\])')):` but that didnt do anything.

Comment: I don't understand. Currently you have `product_li_tags = bs4.find_all(text=re.compile('attributesCombinations'))`. You replace that by `product_li_tags = bs4.find_all(text=re.compile(r'var attributesCombinations = (\[.*?\])'))` and you should be done.

Comment: Ohhh, I should still use that! I did not know that.... .) - Alright gonna test that now

Comment: Alright so I just tried `product_li_tags = bs4.find_all(text=re.compile(r'var attributesCombinations = (\[.*?\])'))`  which gives me back a value of `['var CUSTOMIZE_TEXTFIELD = 1;\nvar FancyboxI18nClose = \'Close\';\nvar FancyboxI18nNext = \'Next\';\nvar FancyboxI18nPrev = \'Previous\';\nvar PS_CATALOG_MODE = false;\nvar added_to_wishlist = \'The product was successfully added to your wishlist.\';\nvar ajax_allowed = true;\nvar ajaxsearch = true;\nvar allowBuyWhenOutOfStock = false;\nvar attribute_anchor_separator = \'-\';\nvar attributesCombinations = [{"id_attribute":"103","id_attr`..

Comment: I believe the solution in that case would be just to split in that case... I will try that!

Answer (score 1):

do not use `re.compile` in bs4, run it directly.

```
match = re.compile('var\s*attributesCombinations\s*=\s*(\[.*?\])').findall(htmlString)
attributesCombinations = json.loads(match[0])
print(attributesCombinations)
```